# FLV file and SWF file

Tags: flash, flv

Just want to confirm whether my current understanding is correct,

1. we can use Flash Player browser plug-in to play both FLV and SWF file;
2. FLV file contains only video/audio, but SWF file could contain not only video/audio but also other information (picture/animaton/etc.).

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

flash player cannot directly play FLV files, you need a FLV player to do that. But you are basically correct .. FLV is a video format like h.264 whereas SWF is an envelope format  and can pretty much hold anything

Comment: Confused, Scott. When you play a video on Youtube, when you right click and then Flash Player is displayed. Looks like flash player could play flv files -- I think Youtube stores and renders flv files at server side? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: on youtube etc,  flash player 9/10 is playing an SWF applet which in turn is streaming the FLV

Comment: "an SWF applet" -- which applet do you mean?

Comment: i mean a program written in actionscript that is then compiled into an SWF (SWFs hold executables too!) that utilized Flashplayer's support of the FLV format to offer a UI, and fetch the video stream and deliver it. On youtube the movie player applet has a name like watch.swf

Comment: so the web page on youtube has an <embed> tag that holds the watch.swf 'program' (compiled AS) there are params that specify how to find the FLV file (youtube tries hard to hide those) and then watch.swf's job is to get the flv, show you some start/stop/fullscreen controls, and display it

Comment: Thanks Scott. My stupid! :-(
1. Could you point me to the URL of the Youtube swf based flv player please? I searched for watch.swf on youtube but failed.
2. "Flashplayer's support of the FLV format" -- Flash player support FLV format but can not play it directly? Confused. :-)

Comment: "so the web page on youtube has an <embed> tag" -- where did you find it?

Comment: I see something like "http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/watch-vfl84938.swf" from source of html page of a youtube video, not sure whether it is what you mean watch.swf?

Comment: there is an open source flv player written in actionscript you can look at over at sourceforge .. link: http://as3flvplayer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks "Flashplayer's support of the FLV format" -- Could you explaint why you said Flash player support FLV format but Flash player can not play it directly? Confused. :-)

Comment: Flash Player understands the Flash Video format and can stream videos to a component. It understands MP3 too. But that does NOT constitute an FLV or MP3 player. You still need media controls, volume & sizing controls, decorations and skinning, etc.

Comment: Have you read dirkgently's reply and his recommended document here, looks like Adobe Flash Player could play flv file direcly, but I have not figure it out?

Here is the link he mentioned, any comments or ideas?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flv/

Answer (score 2):

> we can use Flash Player browser plug-in to play both FLV and SWF file;

Yes. From [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flv/) for FLV:

> [...] Flash Player can also play FLV files directly with MIME type video/x-flv. An FLV file encodes synchronized audio and video streams.

As for your other question:

> FLV file contains only video/audio, but SWF file could contain not only video/audio but also other information (picture/animaton/etc.)

Yes. Again, I'd refer you back to the [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/):

> The SWF file format delivers vector graphics, text, video, and sound over the Internet and is supported by Adobe® Flash® Player and Adobe AIR™ software. Flash Player already reaches over 98% of Internet-enabled desktops and more than 800 million handsets and mobile devices.
>
> The SWF file format is designed to be an efficient binary delivery format, not a format for exchanging graphics between graphics editors.

Other questions:

> One more questions, how to use Adobe Flash player manually?

What happens when you double click on a SWF file on your system? Typically, flash player standalone version should come up and play the SWF file. You have to figure out where the executable resides on your system.

> Any ideas about how to make Adobe Flash Player play the flv file file so that I can have a try?

You can drag and drop your flv on the standalone player.

Comment: One more questions, how to use Adobe Flash player manually? I am so stupid that I have tried hard but can not find a way to use Adobe Flash player in the same way as Media player to point it to a flv movie. by default, it is played by Adobe Media Player and not played by Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: (continued) Any ideas about how to make Adobe Flash Player play the flv file file so that I can have a try?

Comment: "You can drag and drop your flv on the standalone player" -- what is the executable file name for Flash Player? I find all stuff by Adobe on my computer but can not find it out.

Comment: Posting your question in any one place is sufficient. Search your system for 'FlashPlayer.exe'. It is typically found inside somewhere inside the c:\Program Files\ folder (depending on what all programs you have installed, such as Flex Builder, Flash CS3 etc).

Comment: No dirkgently, I have searched there is no program called flashplayer.exe on my computer, but when pointing to page which requires Flash Player like youtube, movies could be played successfully. This is exactly why I am so confused. Any ideas?

Comment: You can play flash files in a browser because you have the browser plugins installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

With Adobe Flash Player plugin, you can view SWF on web browser, but not FLV.
For FLV needs to be exported to a web-based flv player.
So to put FLV to web page and play it, you just need a FLV player.
SWF can be a FLV player that control the playing of FLV files.
[Moyea Web Player](http://www.playerdiy.com/) is a good flash video player creator, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up since I ran into this problem today and just in case anyone runs across this.

Windows Server 2003 and IIS do not know how to handle FLV files properly. So if you had a SWF that pulls in FLV's, it's not going to work.

You need to load up IIS, right click the local computer, properties, MIME TYPES. And add this:

extension: .flv
MIME: flv-application/octet-stream